# 502 Bad Gateway Nginx & Chef Server

Tags: nginx, chef-infra

I've upgraded my chef server. Then I ran `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` successfully. 
However, when I ran `chef-server-ctl test`, I got error:

```
Encountered an error attempting to create client pedant_admin_client
Response Code was: 502

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.4.4
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does `chef-server-ctl status` say?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same thing: Here is what I did to solve the problem.

Chef has logs but a lot of services. Check which one is failing

`chef-server-ctl` status will indicate what is down.

Go look at that log under

```
/var/log/chef-server/<problem-service>/current
```

My particular problem was

```
2014-09-27_17:33:32.41439 FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Invalid argument
2014-09-27_17:33:32.41441 DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=4050755584, 03600).
2014-09-27_17:33:32.41442 HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMMAX parameter.  You can either reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMMAX.  To reduce the request size (currently 4050755584 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
```

Thus all I needed to do was `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` 
problem solved

Comment: Pleas note that using `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` will not remove your organizations

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

```
sudo chef-server-ctl upgrade
```

WARNING: my org was preserved, but your results may vary

I ran into this too. I suspect an unexpected. "apt-get upgrade". For me all checks pass in status.

```
chef-server-ctl status
```

but this failed

```
sudo chef-server-ctl test
```

I ran this for more details (beware thousands of lines of output ;- )

```
sudo chef-server-ctl tail
```

and found this gem: (note the ".." in the path indicating a path misconfig)

```
2015-08-24_23:00 mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/opscode/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../var': Permission denied
```

I then ran this and it worked

```
sudo chef-server-ctl upgrade
```